Generating dictionary with list as values from JSON with Python
I have JSON response from API, which lists license expirations. Once company may have multiple licenses. JSON has lot of data, that I do not need. All I need is a company name and list of license expiration dates.
My idea is to extract all company names and use them as dictionary keys, then value would be a list containing license expiration dates. I can extract company names and create a dictionary with company names as keys, but I do not know how to collect license dates and correlate them with specific company.
Bellow is an example of API JSON response. It is truncated to include only two records from the same "test" company (I believe this is sufficient to demonstrate the structure), but full output would have multiple companies with multiple licenses.
So "company_name" contains the company name value and "expiration_time" contains the license expiration date.
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "62525384-e0b8-4a54-9600-13e0eccf1ac2",
      "type": "licenses",
      "attributes": {
        "uuid": "62525384-e0b8-4a54-9600-13e0eccf1ac2",
        "start_time": "2018-08-24 00:00:00 +0300",
        "expiration_time": "2019-08-24 00:00:00 +0300",
        "limit_hosts": 1,
        "order_code": null,
        "comments": null,
        "organization_id": "07b05efa-6c5e-40d2-ab7f-348a19f02d71",
        "organization": {
          "data": {
            "id": "07b05efa-6c5e-40d2-ab7f-348a19f02d71",
            "type": "organizations",
            "attributes": {
              "uuid": "07b05efa-6c5e-40d2-ab7f-348a19f02d71",
              "name": "tetete",
              "parent_organization": 48,
              "company_name": "tetete",
              "created_at": "2018-08-24 15:24:14 +0300",
              "excluded_from_licenses": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "90f6dd88-9260-47a2-82c1-45838659e781",
      "type": "licenses",
      "attributes": {
        "uuid": "90f6dd88-9260-47a2-82c1-45838659e781",
        "start_time": "2018-08-24 14:09:38 +0300",
        "expiration_time": "2020-07-21 00:00:00 +0300",
        "limit_hosts": 0,
        "order_code": null,
        "comments": null,
        "organization_id": "8d9637af-fe33-48ab-b0b0-7728929c8171",
        "organization": {
          "data": {
            "id": "8d9637af-fe33-48ab-b0b0-7728929c8171",
            "type": "organizations",
            "attributes": {
              "uuid": "8d9637af-fe33-48ab-b0b0-7728929c8171",
              "name": "tetete",
              "parent_organization": 24,
              "company_name": "tetete",
              "created_at": "2018-08-24 14:09:38 +0300",
              "excluded_from_licenses": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total_count": 133,
      "total_pages": 14,
      "per_page": 10,
      "current_page": 1
    },
    "total_licenses": 247
  }
}

My code at the moment looks like this
def ExtractLicenseDetails():
    LicenceLibrary = dict()
    TempOrgList = []
    for licence in lic["data"]:
        TempOrgList.append(licence["attributes"]["organization"]["data"]["attributes"]["name"])
    LicenceLibrary = dict.fromkeys(TempOrgList, list()) # no we create dictionary keys from non unique list of organisation, getting rid of duplicates in the process
    for licence in lic["data"]:
         LicenceLibrary[licence["attributes"]["organization"]["data"]["attributes"]["name"]].append(licence["attributes"]["expiration_time"])
    print(LicenceLibrary)

Needles to say, It doesn't work, but that I mean that wrong expiration dates get added to the lists.

What is lic["data"] in your code? Please post a [mre]! And add some details: What did you expect to get and what did you get instead?

hate to suggest this, but Redis is good for this, or worse sqlite.  or in memory-sqlite.

Have you looked at collections.defaultdict() and or .setdefault()?

Your code looks kind of unintuitive, as the comments already say, it'd be good if you provided an mre and the correct and actual output from your code, regardless, this is what i would have done instead (+mre):

lic = {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "62525384-e0b8-4a54-9600-13e0eccf1ac2",
      "type": "licenses",
      "attributes": {
        "uuid": "62525384-e0b8-4a54-9600-13e0eccf1ac2",
        "start_time": "2018-08-24 00:00:00 +0300",
        "expiration_time": "2019-08-24 00:00:00 +0300",
        "limit_hosts": 1,
        "order_code": None,
        "comments": None,
        "organization_id": "07b05efa-6c5e-40d2-ab7f-348a19f02d71",
        "organization": {
          "data": {
            "id": "07b05efa-6c5e-40d2-ab7f-348a19f02d71",
            "type": "organizations",
            "attributes": {
              "uuid": "07b05efa-6c5e-40d2-ab7f-348a19f02d71",
              "name": "tetete",
              "parent_organization": 48,
              "company_name": "tetete",
              "created_at": "2018-08-24 15:24:14 +0300",
              "excluded_from_licenses": True
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "90f6dd88-9260-47a2-82c1-45838659e781",
      "type": "licenses",
      "attributes": {
        "uuid": "90f6dd88-9260-47a2-82c1-45838659e781",
        "start_time": "2018-08-24 14:09:38 +0300",
        "expiration_time": "2020-07-21 00:00:00 +0300",
        "limit_hosts": 0,
        "order_code": None,
        "comments": None,
        "organization_id": "8d9637af-fe33-48ab-b0b0-7728929c8171",
        "organization": {
          "data": {
            "id": "8d9637af-fe33-48ab-b0b0-7728929c8171",
            "type": "organizations",
            "attributes": {
              "uuid": "8d9637af-fe33-48ab-b0b0-7728929c8171",
              "name": "tetete",
              "parent_organization": 24,
              "company_name": "tetete",
              "created_at": "2018-08-24 14:09:38 +0300",
              "excluded_from_licenses": True
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "total_count": 133,
      "total_pages": 14,
      "per_page": 10,
      "current_page": 1
    },
    "total_licenses": 247
  }
}

expiration_dates = {}

for licence in lic["data"]:
    name = licence["attributes"]["organization"]["data"]["attributes"]["company_name"] ## idk if you wanna use name or company_name, in your explanation it says company_name but you used name, DECIDE!!!!
    expiration_time = licence["attributes"]["expiration_time"]
    if name in expiration_dates.keys():
        expiration_dates[name].append(expiration_time)
    else:
        expiration_dates[name] = [expiration_time]


print(expiration_dates)

Note: please, please use the pep-8 standard, it makes everything a lot cleaner, even though i myself am not a fan of snake case either. IF you wanna stick to camel case or something, just use the rename function in your favourite editor

I would leverage collections.defaultdict() or the setdefault() of your dictionary to dynamically add keys whos values are lists, then append to those lists.
Given your example data from above as a string and then cast to a dictionary say like:
lic = json.loads(json_payload)

Then I would create a method that accepted a dictionary and returned your required dictionary.
def extract_license_details(lic):
    licence_library = {}
    for licence in lic["data"]:
        company_name = licence["attributes"]["organization"]["data"]["attributes"]["name"]
        company_licence_expires = licence["attributes"]["expiration_time"]
        licence_library.setdefault(company_name, []).append(company_licence_expires)
    return licence_library

When passed the dictionary lic per your json payload, you would expect to get back:
{'tetete': ['2019-08-24 00:00:00 +0300', '2020-07-21 00:00:00 +0300']}


Thank you, it does work and is probably a more "elegant" solution, but @NoBlockhit answer is easier for me to understand, given my limited experience. Actually, both suggested solutions produce exactly the same output.
